# How to output javascript in both a standalone and a dependency file in a gulp workflow

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have lots of small projects I have developed in javascript that can be used as a standalone script or as a dependency for other scripts. If all my scripts have `module.exports = ObjName` at the end of them so that they can be used as a resource in a CommonJS environment they will generate errors when used as a standalone script in a web environment.

Considering that I am using Gulp workflows to develop my scripts what is that best way to build a version as a dependency and a version for standalone web integration?

Are their any good examples of libraries doing this on github?

Comment: I'm quite not sure about what do you mean by `standalone script in a web environment`? Is that, including them with `script` tag?

Comment: Have you considered using [browserify](https://npmjs.org/package/browserify) for the web environment?

Comment: @code-jaff Yes I am talking about scripts included using the script tag.

Comment: @Ben I don't want to have to force users to have to use Browserify to use my script. A lot of users wouldn't be anywhere near the level of using node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this solution](http://www.evanjones.ca/js-modules.html). It tests for module and module.exports property

```
// new namespace object defined by this file
var mylib = {};
// import used by this file
var dependency = dependency || require('./dependency');  
(function(){

    // define properties on mylib, use dependency

    // export the namespace object
    if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
        module.exports = mylib;
    }
})();
```